# segmentation fault while accessing an array element's

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

here is my problem, I malloc my array like that:

```
e->map = malloc(sizeof(int *) * e->map_y);
i = -1;
while (++i < e->map_x)
    e->map[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * e->map_x);
```

where e->map_y = 14 and e->map_x = 10
The problem is I can't access (I have a segfault) elements after e->map[10][0] (included)
I tough about I invert x and y but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

I can post my entire code if necessary, thx

hi, I added the entire project on github for more details: https://github.com/42-hbock/fdf

this part of the code is in src/default_reading.c, the malloc is in the function char       *default_reading(char *file, t_env *e) and I have the segmentation fault while accessing in void        create_int_map(char *cmap, t_env *e)

Comment: The while should be checking for e->map_y, not e->map_x, because that is the size of the first array you allocated.

Comment: It is segfaulting because you didn't malloc 14 arrays, you only allocated 10!

Comment: Jiminion I checked e->map_y with a printf just before the first malloc, and it's equal to 14

Comment: right, so you should allocate 14 arrays for it, not the 10 you are currently allocating....

Comment: there are several errors in the code logic.  here is one: in default_reading() this line: 'char *c_map;' is soon followed by this line: 'c_map = ft_reallocat(c_map, buf);'  However, c_map contains some trash value, not NULL nor a pointer to some allocated memory,  The results of performing a realloc function is undefined behaviourl leads to corruption of the heap and a seg fault event.  suggest changing 'char *c_map'; to 'char *c_map = NULL;'  In reality, it is always a good idea to initialize any variable when it is defined.

Comment: Hi user...., c_map is already initialized in char  *init_string(char *s), or maybe I didn't understand what u mean?

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
e->map = malloc(sizeof(int *) * e->map_y);
i = -1;
while (++i < e->map_y)
    e->map[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * e->map_x);
```

The change is having the while look at e->map_y instead of e->map_x.  The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: I prefer a `for` loop. That `-1` gives me the creeps.

Comment: Sorry but it is for a school project we have a norm and I can't use for loops, by the way I already try to change map_y and map_x

Comment: Change the value that the while is comparing.  The code you have written is incorrect.

Comment: I already change the variable with a row number, 14

Comment: Or even (how the heck can you format code in comments?) i = 0; while (i < e->map_y) { e->map [i] = ...; i++}  Makes the intent MUCH clearer, and that makes finding the problem easier.